# React testing extracting assertions jest error

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I added eslint to a project and came across a "test has no assertions" error coming from jest/expect-expect. In the code below the render and click have been extracted because of repetition, how do I fix the error besides disabling it for the file?

```
it('triggers onAssignToClick when the assign button is clicked', () => {
  testButtonClick('assign-button', onAssignToClickFn)
})

const testButtonClick = (buttonName, callback) => {
  const { getByTestId } = renderComponent()

  fireEvent.click(getByTestId(buttonName))
  expect(callback).toHaveBeenCalled()
}

const renderComponent = (props) => {
  return render(
    <Context.Provider value={props.viewport}>
      <Actions {...props} />
    </Context.Provider>
  )
}
```

Comment: Do you mean the ESLint Jest plugin's [`jest/expect-expect`](https://github.com/jest-community/eslint-plugin-jest/blob/master/docs/rules/expect-expect.md) rule?

Comment: Yes, I edited the question

Comment: So did you look at the rule's documentation? You can configure what counts as an expectation, so if you name all your expectation wrappers `test...` for example you could match for that.

Comment: I did look at the documentation but is that my only option?

Comment: What do you mean? The documentation shows you all the configuration options, or you can turn the rule off, or you can keep the expectations in the test (`testButtonClick('assign-button'); expect(callback).toHaveBeenCalled(onAssignToClickFn)`).